# Blur and focus method is not working in textfield for sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can any body tell how to implement focus and blur method in sencha touch for ios

I have tried this way

```
Ext.getComponent('txtName').focus();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your textfield looks like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    itemId: 'txtName' // Best practice is to use itemId instead of id
}
```

You can select it then with [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery):

```
var txtName = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#txtName')[0];

txtName.focus();
```